# "Open" Method Error with ADO Connection in Excel/Access

Tags: vba, ado

I keep getting an error when trying to open a database using an ADO connection in VBA - I am getting the following error:

Run-time error '-2147467259 (80004005)': 
Method 'Open' of object '_Recordset' failed

I have checked an re-checked all of my file paths and syntax, and cannot find what is wrong with the code below - can anyone help?

```
Public Sub PlainTextQuery()

Dim rsData As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sConnect As String
Dim sSQL As String

Dim sCusip As String

sCusip = Trim(Range("cusip").Value)

' Create the connection string
sConnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " & _
    "Data Source=C:\Users\intern\Documents\NewStuff\ResiOffers_v1.accdb;"

' Create the SQL statement
sSQL = "SELECT Date, Cusip, Bond, OF, CF, Dealer, Price, Matcher, DayCount, MktValue " & _
    "FROM ResiOffersColor " & _
    "WHERE Cusip = 16163HAE1 " & _
    "ORDER BY Date;"

' Create the recordset object and run the query
Set rsData = New ADODB.Recordset
rsData.Open sSQL, sConnect, adOpenForwardOnly, _
    adLockReadOnly, adCmdText

' Make sure we get records back
If Not rsData.EOF Then
    ' Dump the contents onto the worksheet
    Sheet2.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rsData
    ' Close the recordset object
    rsData.Close
Else
    ' Close the recordset object
    rsData.Close
    MsgBox "Error: No records returned.", vbCritical
End If

' Destroy the recordset object
Set rsData = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Whomever is executing the function must have write access to the directory because ms-access is going to try to create a lock (ldb) file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I just got the code working by putting brackets [] around each of my field names in the SQL query string...but now have a new problem - no records are printing in my excel workbook.  I am not getting the "no records returned error", so it seems that something is wrong with my attempt to print the records, not in retrieving the records...

Answer (score 0):

The problem here is the `sSQL` statement.
This line:

```
"WHERE Cusip = 16163HAE1 " & _
```

Should be replaced with:

```
"WHERE Cusip = '16163HAE1' " & _
```

In SQL, you enclosed string or text with `'` (apostrophe).